# Global variable scoping in Davinci Resolve Fusion?

Tags: davinci-resolve, fusion

The code below is a Null.fuse node, packed with debugging statements.

I'm running it under Davinci Resolve 18.1.4 beta 9.

```lua
print("Debug: script start")
print(test)
test = 0
print(test)

FuRegisterClass("ScopeTest", CT_Tool, {
    REGS_Name = "ScopeTest",
    REGS_Category = "Color",
    REGS_OpIconString = "fCL",
    REGS_OpDescription = "ScopeTest",
    REG_OpNoMask = true,
    REG_NoBlendCtrls = true,
    REG_NoObjMatCtrls = true,
    REG_NoMotionBlurCtrls = true,
    })

function Create()
    print("Debug: Create start")
    print(test)

    InImage = self:AddInput("Input", "Input", {
        LINKID_DataType = "Image",
        LINK_Main = 1,
        })

    OutImage = self:AddOutput("Output", "Output", {
        LINKID_DataType = "Image",
        LINK_Main = 1,
        })              

    InButton = self:AddInput("Button", "Button", {
        INPID_InputControl = "ButtonControl",
        INP_DoNotifyChanged = true,
        INP_External = false,
        })

    test = 1
    print(test)
    print("Debug: Create end")
end

function Process(req)
    print("Debug: Process start")
    print(test)

    local img = InImage:GetValue(req)
    OutImage:Set(req, img)

    test = 2
    print(test)
    print("Debug: Process end")
end

function NotifyChanged(inp, param, time)
    print("Debug: Notify start")
    print(test)
    test = 3
    print(test)
    print("Debug: Notify end")
end

print(test)
test = 4
print(test)
print("Debug: script end")
```

My expectation is for the global *test* variable to be 3 after pushing the button, and for it to be still 3 when entering *Process*.

This is what I observe in the console instead:

```
[...]
Debug: Notify start
3
3
Debug: Notify end
Debug: Notify start
3
3
Debug: Notify end
Debug: Process start
2
2
Debug: Process end
```

I'm very confused by *test* still being 2 after entering *Process*.

Any help appreciated!